# 5v signal output to 3.3v analog dc

Tags: adc, voltage-divider

I have a current sensor (ACS712) that is powered from 5V.
And a microcontroller that is powered from 3.3V.
Sensitivity of the ACS712 is 100mV/A. When there is no current, its signal out pin outputs VCC/2 (so 2.5V), and then goes +100mV/A depending on the current it reads through the i+/i- wires I drew below.
ACS712 can read current up to 20A. My circuit is expected to draw current from 0 to 10A at most.

I need to convert the signal output (that can range from 2.5V to 5V), to something that my microcontroller can read without being fried (that is 3.3V max).

I set up a basic voltage divider, but now my ADC pin on the microcontroller reads 0V no matter what (and so does a DMM). What did I do wrong? R1 is 2.2K Ohms and R2 is 3.3K Ohms

[image]

Comment: maybe the output already has an internal series resistor ... check the datasheet

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" Do you mean besides using MS Paint to draw a schematic? :D Check it with the DMM without the divider, and reading no current. Is the output 2.5V? If it is try adding the divider but not the ADC. Measure the center of the divider with the DMM, is the voltage 1.5V? If it is try adding the ADC and measure with the DMM again. The datasheet shows a minimum resistance on the output of 4.7K, you're divider is 5.5k so it's within the specs. I don't know what the input impedance of your ADC is though, you'd have to figure that in as well.

Comment: With divider removed, and some sensed current passing, what does your DMM say ACS712 output is? Then, when the divider is in place, what is that measurement?